# Get an XElement's position and length in the original document

Tags: c#, xml, position, linq-to-xml

I am parsing an XML document for specific nodes, and would like to later on show the xml document in a ui, highlighting the specific portions. To do this, I need to know the position of the element in the document's text, and its length.

So far, I have found, that when loading the XDocument, I should specify `LoadOptions.SetLineInfo`, so I can at least get the position in the original xml string. This gives me the char, at which the element's name starts, so I should subtract one, to get the actual start of the tag. I have, however, not been able to find a way to get the position of the ending element.

What I've tried so far (LinqPad code using `.Dump()`, substitute with `Console.WriteLine` if necessary), the basic test code:

```
var xml = @"<xml>
  <myElement>
    <someProperty attribu=""attrVal1"" />
    <someOtherProp />
  </myElement>
</xml>";
// xml.Length => 105 (Note, there should be a TAB instead of four spaces before `<someOtherProp />`,
//                    to demonstrate problems)

var doc = XDocument.Parse(xml, LoadOptions.SetLineInfo);

var li = (IXmlLineInfo)doc;
$"{li.LineNumber - 1}:{li.LinePosition - 1}~{GetLen(doc.Root)}".Dump();

foreach (var el in doc.XPathSelectElements("//myElement/*"))
{
    li = (IXmlLineInfo) el;
    $"{li.LineNumber - 1}:{li.LinePosition - 1}~{GetLen(el)}".Dump();
}
```

Now, my implementations of `GetLen`:

First attempt: using `.ToString()`

```
int GetLen(XElement el)
{
    return el.ToString().Length;
}
```

This will reformat the code, so the TAB mentioned in the comment above will be expanded to four spaces instead. The `doc` will be 108 chars instead of 105 now. So, this is not an option.

Second attempt: using an XmlReader

```
int GetLen(XElement el)
{
    using (var r = el.CreateReader())
    {
        r.MoveToContent();
        var ox = r.ReadOuterXml();
        return ox.Length;
    }
}
```

This will throw out any unneccessary white space, leading to much shorter lengths (86 for `doc`). So, this is also not an option.

I have not been able to find any other meaningful way to accomplish what I need, other than manually parsing the XML myself, which I would like to avoid doing. Does anyone have an idea, what else I could try?

I could, of course, read in the xml, reformat it, and then use one of the options. But, since the XML is delivered by an external party, and we want to tell them, where we found mistakes, it would be best to know their indexes, and not the indexes after reformatting.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Well, the length was just for testing. I'm rather looking for the length of the specific elements I select using the XPath expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems, this is currently not possible. We have instead opted to generate an XPath expression pointing to the exact element. This way, we can leave the formatting to whatever the UI wishes to do, but always have the correct element.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by creating your own proxy around the `XmlReader` class, passing it to `XDocument.Load()` and manually matching the opening and closing tags from your proxy each time `XmlReader` calls `Read()`. A simplified version of this looks like this:

```
    struct LineCol
    {
        public int Line, Col;

        public LineCol(IXmlLineInfo info)
        {
            Line = info.LineNumber - 1;
            Col = info.LinePosition - 1;
        }

        public LineCol(int line, int col)
        {
            Line = line;
            Col = col;
        }
    }

    class ReaderProxy : XmlReader, IXmlLineInfo
    {
        private XmlReader _Inner;
        private IXmlLineInfo _InnerLineInfo;

        class StackEntry
        {
            public string Name;
            public LineCol Position;
        }

        Stack<StackEntry> _ElementStack = new Stack<StackEntry>();

        public ReaderProxy(XmlReader inner)
        {
            _Inner = inner;
            _InnerLineInfo = (IXmlLineInfo)inner;
        }

  
        public Dictionary<LineCol, LineCol> StartToEndLineMap = 
                            new Dictionary<LineCol, LineCol>();

        public override bool Read()
        {
            if (!_Inner.Read())
                return false;

            if (_Inner.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element && !_Inner.IsEmptyElement)
            {
                _ElementStack.Push(new StackEntry { 
                      Name = _Inner.Name, 
                      Position = new LineCol(this)
                  });
            }
            else if (_Inner.NodeType == XmlNodeType.EndElement)
            {
                var el = _ElementStack.Pop();
                if (el.Name != _Inner.Name)
                    throw new Exception("Unbalanced element stack");

                StartToEndLineMap.Add(el.Position, new LineCol(this));
            }

            return true;
        }

    }
```

The remaining methods overridden from `XmlReader` should just call the corresponding methods in `_Inner`/`_InnerLineInfo` (VS can generate those automatically).

You can then use the proxy to find the end location of each element like this:

```
var proxy = new ReaderProxy(XmlReader.Create(text));
var document = XDocument.Load(proxy, LoadOptions.SetLineInfo);
XElement element = ...;
var endPos = proxy.StartToEndLineMap[new LineCol((IXmlLineInfo)element)];
```

Comment: Thanks for this idea. I will try it out, once I get back to this topic.

Comment: No worries, I know it's an old and very niche question, but I recently faced exactly the same problem and that's what got googled up. FWIW, I used the whole proxy thing for finding the element bounds in an internal XAML refactoring tool and it worked very reliably and much faster than other options, so I thought i'd share it here. Cheers.